# Route a particular process over another gateway

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing

I have 2 internet connections on differnet interfaces. I have eth0 which is internal ip of 192.168.1.70 and then I have another network connection to a different network which is on wlan0 192.168.43.193.

I want to use the 1.70 as my primary interface, however I'd like to have everything except Deluged go out of the eth0 and all connections for deluge go out of wlan0 (43.193)

I understand that you can only have one default gateway which currently I have to change depending on what I wish to do. I would prefer to keep my main outbound connections going via eth0 but still able to use wlan0 for specific processes.

How can I go about this?